# Javascript - perform something in certain intervals in FOR LOOP

Tags: php, javascript

I got a problem while developing javascript based idea..

Here's the main code,

```
 $.post("datainlines.php", function(data) { 

        var lines = data.split("\n");

           for (var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {

             sitename= lines[i]; sitetype=lines[i++]; 

             if(i/2 == '0'){ alert current values in sitename and sitetype variables}

            }

       } );
```

This will get data in datainlines.php via POST, datainlines.php file data structure is like this -

```
Google
search
Stackoverflow
Questions
Yahoo
search
Facebook
social network
```

How to get site name and type in groups, like

```
Google
search
```

then

```
Stackoverflow
questions
```

is there anyway to group out and alert per every two loops in for loop ?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question but this looks very wrong `i/2 == '0'`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Increment your loop value by two:

```
$.post("datainlines.php", function(data) {

    var lines = data.split("\n");

    for (var i = 1; i < lines.length; i+=2) {
        sitename = lines[i];
        sitetype = lines[i+1];
        alert(sitename + " " + sitetype);
    }
});​
```

Note the `i+=2` in the for loop. This will skip every other entry in the array.

---

As an aside, I think with this line:

```
if(i/2 == '0')
```

What you were actually looking for is the modulus:

```
if(i % 2 === 0)
```